# How can I make this mysql query faster? Is the order a killer? The limit?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT *  FROM table WHERE city LIKE example ORDER by RAND() Limit 10
```

I'm trying to return, obv, some random entries from a table, but it's on quite a few pages that get hit so it can cause the site to slow down. I comment out the query and all is well again so I know it's this, but I'd like to take this opportunity to learn a bit about how to do queries better.

I thought an index might help, but where there's no joins that seems unhelpful in this case.  Thanks.

Comment: RAND() gets called every row. Using a "LIKE" is going to be slow DEPENDING on what "example" is. Give a real example

Comment: Is it fast without `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`? That will tell you if that part is the killer.

Comment: example could be san francisco or new york.

Comment: so I just ran a query to SELECT * FROM California WHERE city LIKE 'san jose' & there were 250k results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make this faster by adding an index on `table(city)`.

I think the query would be clearer using `=` rather than `like`:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM table t
WHERE t.city = example
ORDER by RAND()
Limit 10;
```

Depending on how many rows are returned, there might be further optimizations.

For instance, one method is:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM (SELECT t.*, RAND() as rnd, (@rn := @rn + 1) as rn
      FROM table t CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @rn := 0) params
      WHERE t.city = example
     ) t 
WHERE rnd < (100 / @rn)  -- get a sample of about 100 records
ORDER BY rnd
LIMIT 10;
```

This uses variables and the `WHERE` to limit the rows to about 100 before sorting.  That sort should be pretty fast.